# Add Instagram to UIActivityViewController Share Swift

Tags: swift, instagram, uiactivityviewcontroller

I implemented this in Obj-C before but couldn't make it work on swift. I would like to be able to share photos to Instagram as well as other standard apps.

```
- (IBAction)thirdOne:(id)sender {
    NSDictionary *fruitParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.fruitName, @"Fruit Name",nil];

    NSString* imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/instagramShare.igo", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:nil];

    UIImage *instagramImage = self.image;
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(instagramImage) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

    self.dic=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]];
    self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES ];
}
```

This is how the button looked:

[image: fruit face ios instagram share]

And this is what happened when the button was clicked:

[image: fruit face ios instagram will smith]

Comment: Could you provide some sample code of what you tried? This is a bit too broad...